# stripped down drools guvnor

Tags: editor, designer, drools

I need to integrate drools guvnor into my application but I think it is a bit overkill for my needs, I don't need an external application... I just need the editors nothing else.

Are there a way to only use these without using the entire thing? I know I can use embedded mode, but I still have to have a full working guvnor instance installed and running

what I am asking for is just a dependency or something without the whole thing.... Is there such a thing? Or do I have to strip it down manually?

Comment: Nope! Actually, no-one even gave me a single comment :)

Comment: In theory, it should be possible since the entire UI is GWT, it should be possible to separate the designer from the rest relatively easy... But I didn't have the time to do that yet.. I will get there sometime though.. If I had any progress I will post it here.. If you did Please do too.