# Local version of Drools Guvnor

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine, drools-guvnor

I've read many stuff about Drools Guvnor and the interaction with Drools Planner. It would be very useful to create and change rules, without coding them. But I've read that Guvnor is a webapplication.

**Is there a solution to run Guvnor as local desktop application?**

I want to use it on my desktop without starting an application server or so.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Currently not (there's a [old proof of concept of Esteban](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10301052/stripped-down-drools-guvnor), but that's a prototype). For uberfire and guvnor 6, they are taking this requirement along I think, but it probably will only make guvnor 6.1 (manstis might be able to elaborate).

In any case, once you have the RuleBase/KnowledgeBase/KieBase from guvnor, it's just a matter of following [documentation section 5.3.4.2.2. A RuleBase (possibly defined by Guvnor)](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.5.0.Final/drools-planner-docs/html_single/index.html#d0e3759). For Planner 6.0, I am looking into making the RuleBase/KnowledgeBase/KieBase [casting pains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11017613/live-rule-creation-in-drools-planner) go away.

Comment: Thx for your reply. The documentation link you've posted is only helpful if I could run Guvnor. Without a webserver (or application server) I could not use Guvnor. I cannot teach my clients to run Guvnor in Eclipse with a local JBoss, glassfish, or something else. But I think waiting for version 6.1 would be a good solution. ;-)